# Resize Font For Unicode

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to resize unicode characters.

[image: Divide symbol is smaller than others]

The divide symbol alone is small even though I've mentioned via code to explicitly increase font size for all buttons. The divide button's title is set as

divideButton.setTitle("\u{F7}", for:normal)

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code, the divide symbol scales just fine:

```swift
button.setTitle("\u{F7}", for: .normal)
button.titleLabel?.font = button.titleLabel?.font.withSize(100)
```

[image]